# Define a 2-d list as an integrable step function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Is it possible in Mathematica to output a two-dimensional list of any length as a step function without defining it manually, but which can be integrated at the same time? Example: I have the list

```
RhoArr={{-1,0.3},{-0.5,0.2},{0,0.1},{0.5,0.2},{1,0.3},...}
```

and I want to define it with a function $f(x)$, so we get the following output:

$$f(-1\leq x <-0.75)=0.3,\\f(-0.75\leq x <-0.25)=0.2,\\f(-0.25\leq x <0.25)=0.1,\\...$$

I have tried to proceed analogously to other programming languages, but Mathematica gives me difficulties with the integration. For example, I get the correct function values from the code (see below), the plot of the function is also perfect, but during integration I get the error (for testing I had used different numbers than above)

```
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.    
Part::pspec: Part specification {}[[1,1]] is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers.
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand {{-1.,0.0326126},{-0.666667,0.0744685},{-0.333333,0.147045},{0,0.491747},{0.333333,0.147045},{0.666667,0.0744685},{1.,0.0326126}}[[{}[[1,1]],2]] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
```

Here is my procedure (this is the last variant I tried)

```
f[x_] := Which[x > 0, Select[X, (0 <= Abs[# - x] <= HalfStep ) &, 1], x <= 0, Select[X, (0<Abs[#- x] <= HalfStep) && # <= 0 &, 1], True, -1000][[1]];  
g[x_] := RhoArr[[Position[X, f[x]][[1, 1]], 2]];
```

Halfstep is the half step size with which the data points are separated, so you can define when an $x$-value belongs to which $y$-value and Rhoarr is the two-dimensional list.
I am still very new to Mathematica, but after days of searching in vain for a solution, I would like to ask here. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the definition and ourpose of you free variable `X`? If `f` is the function you are trying to construct, what is your reason for introducing `g`? This does not seem to be a well posed question.

Comment: You seem to be using two separate Mathematica accounts, which keeps you from editing your own question without approval.  I recommend that you use one account only.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way: use an interpolating function (with order 0).

```
rhoArr = {{-1, 0.3}, {-0.5, 0.2}, {0, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.2}, {1, 0.3}}; 
f = Interpolation[rhoArr, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

You can use the function f just like any other function. In particular you can integrate it. Here is the integral from -1 to 1:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

First we define the lists for the definition set and the value set, with the requirements, that the value set is distributed symmetrically around $x=0$ and that the integral over the function is unity.

```
NN = 3; (*number of intervals per quadrant*)
XL = N[Range[-1, 0, 1/NN]];
XL = XL[[1 ;; Length[XL] - 1]];
XR = N[Range[0, 1, 1/NN]];
XR = XR[[2 ;; Length[XR]]];
X = Join [XL, XR]];
YL = RandomReal[1/(NN), NN];
YR = Reverse [YL];
Y = Join [YL, YR];
HalfStep = N[1/(2*NN)];
RhoArr = Transpose[{X, Y}];
```

Now we define the desired function

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[
Table[{Y[[k]], 
Which[k == 1, X[[k]] <= x <= X[[k]] + HalfStep, 
k == Length[X], X[[k]] - HalfStep <= x <= X[[k]], 
True, X[[k]] - HalfStep <= x <= X[[k]] + HalfStep]}, 
{k, 1, Length@X}]];
```

and furthermore

```
Zer = (1 - NIntegrate[g[x], {x, -1, 1}])/(2*HalfStep)(*For the integral to be 1*);
X = Insert[X, 0, NN + 1]; 
Y = Insert[Y, Zer, NN + 1];
RhoArr = Transpose[{X, Y}];

NIntegrate[g[x], {x, -1, 1}]]
Plot[g[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}]
```

So everything works.

Thanks to all involved.

## Old response - Question 2

First: I am the one who asked the question. Unfortunately my guest account, with which I wrote this post, and the current real account, which is the one from the guest account, are not connected, although the email matches and I just added a password to the guest account. Therefore I can neither edit my question nor write a comment or ask another question about it. I am sorry for this mess, it is the first time ever that I am in a forum. If anyone can help me clean up this mess, this would be helpful.

To answer m_Goldberg's question above and provide some clarity: Here is the code where the $X$ and $Y$ lists are defined, which in turn define the 2-d list RhoArr; the definitions aim to create a 2-d list with the contents

```
{definition set, value set}
```

where the value set is to be distributed symmetrically around $x=0$.

```
NN = 3;
XL = N[Range[-1, 0, 1/NN]];
XL = XL[[1 ;; Length[XL] - 1]];
XR = N[Range[0, 1, 1/NN]];
XR = XR[[2 ;; Length[XR]]];
X = Join [XL, XR]];
YL = RandomReal[1/(2*NN), NN];
YR = Reverse[YL];
Y = Join[YL, YR];
Zer = 1 - Total [Y];
X = Insert[X, 0, NN + 1];
Y = Insert[Y, Zer, NN + 1];
RhoArr = Transpose[{X, Y}]
HalfStep = N[1/(2*NN)];
```

The problem is actually simple, at least in other programming languages, I just don't know how to solve it in Mathematica.

A short and precise summary of the problem: I have a 2-d list (RhoArr) and want to define a step function from it, which has an input value $x$ (see the mathematically written function $f(x)$ in the original post), which then can be plotted via $x$ and integrated via $x$. My above solution using the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is obviously bad, because it can only be plotted, but not integrated. The plot looks like this

[image]

However, if you integrate this function, the error messages from the original question will appear.

In general: such a mess won't happen to me again and I apologize for that! I will also try to formulate my problems more clearly and completely. All that remains is my justification that I have never done something like this before.

Comment: Look at the function Piecewise -- this is one way to get a function that looks like your f above.

Comment: This is an ingenious advice. The solution went very quickly. The problem is that I do not know the methods of Mathematica. Thanks a lot!!! I searched for "step functions". 

Question: I have solved the problem now, shall I write the answer in general, together with the code that one can see how to solve it?